# System Offline not working

Tags: system-messages, system, offline

I have set the system to offline and double checked this in my config file, yet it doesn't work, I can still view the site when logged out. I have tried on different browsers and devices but the site still shows.

EE version v2.5.3 with MSM installed. Have tried this on 2 of the sites on this install with the same results.

Thanks in advance.
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you're not logged in as Superadmin.  Then also double check that your "Guest" group is not set to be able to view the site when offline.

Hopefully one of those two things is it. :)

Comment: staring me right in the face that one! :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Chrome browser - it's well known to cache like mad, I've seen a lot of issues with it lately not serving up correct page views.